# React redux state is changed but in component view it doesn't update the UI

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-component

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    products: state.priceTabProducts
  };
};

class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Layout>
                <Route path="/:product" component={ProductsPage}/>
                <ProductsTab
                    show={this.props.showPriceTab}
                    quantity={this.props.products.length}
                />
            </Layout>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

I change the state and it working nice, and I want to pass length to the  component but it doesn't change its value. How can I resolve this?

Comment: is products definitely an array? have you console.logged this?

Comment: yeah I keep them as an array.


export function products(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCTS_TAB:
            state.push(action.payload);
            return state;
        default:
            return state
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you mutate the state as a re-render will not be triggered if the reference doesn't change. You should instead use concat to update the array

```
export function priceTabProducts(state = [], action) { 
   switch (action.type) { 
       case PRICE_TAB_PRODUCTS: return state.concat(action.payload);
       default: return state 
   } 
}
```